# Twitter character count and PHP Normalizer

Tags: php, twitter

According to [twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/counting-characters), the [PHP Normalizer](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) method is required to get the proper char count especially for international characters.

Is this the right usage to process a sample message called `$str2count`?

```
$str2count='sample twitter message';
if(!Normalizer.isNormalized($str2count)){
  $str2count = Normalizer.normalize($str2count);
}
```

Comment: Unless Normalizer is a constant there, you're looking for Normalizer::isNormalized.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out:

Multi byte function is a more reliable and cleaner for what you need.

```
$strlen = mb_strlen($str, 'utf-8');
```

For Normalizer:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.isnormalized.php

```
$str='sample twitter message';

if(!Normalizer::isNormalized($str,Normalizer::FORM_C)){
    $str=Normalizer::normalize('A'.$str,Normalizer::FORM_C);
}

$strlen = strlen($str);
```